# How to fix LoadError for loading Escher in julia?

Tags: julia

I'm a beginner to julia and I'm having the problem for loading Escher in julia. Every time when I wanted to import the Package Escher it always has the problems saying:

WARNING: could not import Base.writemime into Escher
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: ""A `Tile` is the basic currency in Escher.
Most of the functions in the Escher API take `Tile`s
among other things as arguments, and return a `Tile` as the result.

Tiles are immutable: once created there is no way to mutate them.
"" is not a valid function argument name

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks. By the way I'm using julia v0.7. I've tried in julia 1.0 before and it also didn't work.

Comment: I think Escher.jl is abandoned. Well, perhaps it's better to say it's 'in limbo'.

Comment: @daycaster thanks. Well, is there any other package for building web GUI in julia?